# Qt application deploy into RPI3 board

Tags: qt

I am deploing a Qt application on a RPI3 board. I run the application, and I am getting the below error message. How to solve these errors?

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
>   This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "eglfs"
>   in "".
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Aborted